# Externing macros and multiply defined symbol in C

Tags: c, linker, c-preprocessor, extern

Here's the problem:
file1.h has the following relevant contents:

```
int var1;
int var2;
#define MACRO1 0x01
#define MACRO2 0x10
#define MACRO3 0x11
```

file1.c contents:

```
#include "file1.h"
...
...
```

Now I have another file2.c in which I want to use the macros and the variables defined in file1.h.
I cannot #include file1.h in file2.c compilation because there are 100 other variables in file.h - so I run into the problem of "multiply defined symbols".

So for the variables in file1.h, I declared them as externs in file2.h.
This takes care of the variables.
But how do I go about with the macros without duplicating them inside file2.h?

Is there any other way for the macros? Also is externing the variables the right way?
FYI: I do not want to modify file1.h or file1.c unnecessarily. Also, I have stated this as an example because I am running into this problem at work and so cannot post direct code.

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: If the macros are useful to multiple files they should really be extracted and refactored into a different header (like a `projectname_macros.h`). The extern requirement implies a design issue. Should both files really need to know those variables? Who do they belong to? Could you solve the extern issue by refactoring those into a new module or by exposing them differently?

Comment: I would argue that modifying `file1.h` to include `extern` on all the variable is a completely necessary change.

Comment: @WilliamPursell in .h files you must not have any other. .h files are not for defining any objects

Comment: @P__J__ I don't understand your comment.  Perhaps my own was unclear.  I am pointing out that it is essential to label the variables in the header with `extern` precisely to avoid defining objects.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I did not understand your comment this way. Actually I do not understand it at all.  **`to include extern on all the variable`** for me you say that he may leave some variable definitions in the header file\

Comment: @P__J__ I'm saying that is is essential to modify the header file in the way you describe in your answer.  The OP states "I do not want to modify file1.h or file1.c unnecessarily", and I am saying that this change is not at all unnecessary, but must be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not define any objects or functions in the ***`.h`*** files, define them in the ***`.c`*** files. In ***`.h`*** files just add `extern` declarations.

## a.h

```
#ifndef A_H_FILE
#define A_H_FILE

#define MACRO1 0x01
#define MACRO2 0x10
#define MACRO3 0x11
extern int var1;
extern int var2;

#endif
```

## a.c

```
#include "a.h"

int var1;
int var2;
```

The variables will be defined only one time, but they will be visible to other compilation units by including ***`a.h`*** file

To avoid macro redefinitions make sure that their names are distinct. Otherwise you will not know which one is correct. To prevent warnings you may

```
#ifdef MACRO1
#undef MACRO1
#endif
#define MACRO1 45654
```

Comment: Re “To prevent warnings you may”: The goal should be to prevent bugs, not to prevent warnings. Seeking to prevent warnings may evade warning messages but leave bugs. The C standard permits duplicate definitions of a macro, so the compiler should not issue a warning if a macro is defined identically twice. So, if the macro definition is the same, there is no need for this workaround. If the macro definition is different, the workaround is concealing some problem in project design. The correct solution is to resolve that problem, not to conceal it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What did I write? But he asked hoe to suppress the warning - and it is the answer.

Comment: What you wrote is “To prevent warnings you may,” and with it you gave a method for avoiding warnings but not for avoiding bugs. The action of undefining a macro and giving a new definition will not resolve a bug in which a source file includes two headers that both define the same macro but with different replacement lists. It always selects the later definition, but the source file may need the earlier definition, or the source file might in fact not be able to work properly with either definition. The presence of different definitions of a macro suggests a bug, and it should be warned about.

Comment: Incidentally, there is no need for the `#ifdef` and `#endif`. The same (bad) result is achieved by using `#undef` unconditionally; it will work whether there is a prior definition or not.

Comment: Further, the question does not ask about dealing with conflicting definitions of macros. It has some macros in file1.h that the OP wants available in file2.c, and OP was considering duplicating the macro definitions in file2.h. That is the wrong approach; file1.h (or some other header) ought to be fixed so that it can be included in file2.c without problems. But, regardless, there would just be, at most, duplicate definitions of macros, which would not cause any compiler complaint. So the proposal in this answer for redefining macros is not only bad but also unneeded.

Comment: In this case, simply remove the `#undef` and let the compiler issue a diagnostic if there are conflicting definitions. That avoids a bug by alerting a human to the problem so they can fix it. This nonsense about a “universal method” to avoid bugs is a straw man: No such argument was made, and a method for avoiding some bugs is not deprived of value because it does not universally avoid all bugs.